# What is the good css approach for the kind of output?

Tags: html

My current output:

[image]

I want to make this kind of output:

[image]

How should I do this? I really don't have any ideas on this.

As of now here is my Html code:

```
<div id="Profile">
    <p class="cover">
        <img src="resources/default-cover.png" alt="">
    </p>
    <p class="profile-pic">
        <a href="#"><img src="resources/default-male.png" alt="Male"></a>
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, your second class is in the wrong place; it should be in the opening paragraph tag, not the closing.

Secondly, try the following(assuming your class placement is correct):

```
.profile-pic {
    margin-top: -50px;
}​
```

Comment: in 3 minutes, just one more thing if i have set background border for the both set of img i noticed I can still see border behind profile-pic class how can I hide it?

Comment: @BrainedWashed I'm not sure I understand your problem, could you take a screen shot, perhaps, or do a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Comment: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RGCgD/), I want to hide that border line inside my profile-pic

Comment: It won't be there if you have actual pictures there.  It's only appearing because you set a specific width and the picture doesn't appear.  See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/RGCgD/1/)

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<div id="Profile">
<p class="cover">
    <img src="resources/default-cover.png" alt="">
</p>
<p class="profile-pic">
    <a href="#"><img src="resources/default-male.png" alt="Male"></a>
</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.profile-pic{
margin-top: -20px;
border-bottom: 40px solid white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your html is not valid with the class placed in the closing p tag. 
There are many ways to do this. Here is one that cleans up your html. 
I usually try to avoid using the p tag unless there are chunks of text inside it.

```
 <div id="Profile"> 

 <img src="resources/default-cover.png" alt="" class="cover"> 

 <a href="#"><img src="resources/default-male.png" alt="Male" class="profile-pic"></a>

 </div>
```

Here is css to accomplish the effects. Place the size of your .profile-pic in the css.

```
 <style type="text/css">
 .cover {display:block;}
 .profile-pic {position:relative; margin-top: -25px;height: 50px; width: 50px;}
 </style>
```